# Full width fixed height Image

Tags: jquery, css, image, responsive-design

How could one make sure that an image is displayed at full width (or fully covering the screen horizontally) with a certain fixed height no matter the width of the screen. If I were to set the `width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` obviously the height would fluctuate with the width of the screen. It doesn't matter if the image will only be shown partially if the screen is narrower. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here is a good example: http://www.teamnine.ch

Try re-sizing your browser window to see what I mean.

Comment: If the height is fixed, why would you do a `height: auto;`?

Comment: That's the thing: I wouldn't. Maybe the way I phrased my question is a bit confusing. Normally one would set the height to auto on full width. But that is what I don't want. Argh, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You mean this image: http://www.teamnine.ch/img/bg/bg_start.jpg

Comment: Yes exactly. It's displayed as an image not a background.

Answer (score 2):

From the source website, it is clear that they have a `min-height` property set. Hence you're getting the result like that. On your desired page too, try the following CSS for your `img` tag.

```
img {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the above (link) website uses a height of **100vh** instead of 100%.

100vh will take the entire height of the window without stretching the image. If you add (for example 50vh), the image will take half of the window. It is somewhat like using percent, but I think, using vh is the right way here.

If you want to make your header like that, try this,

```
header {
   background-image: (image.jpg); 
   height: 100vh; 
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is how to center all the elements inside the header in the center (like the link in question),

```
header {
    background-image: (image.jpg); 
    height :100vh; 
    background-size: cover; 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
    justify-content: centre; 
    alighn-items: centre; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the image in a div:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.outer {
    width:100%;
    height:125px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <img src="inner.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. As long as the image width is set to auto it will adjust with re-size.

Comment: But the container div should crop anything that's higher than 125px. Isn't that what you want?